# Unity creating 3d clothes for game character

Tags: unity, 3d, animation, rigging

I am trying to make a system where players can change out their clothes with others if they like, and even layer up clothes such as covering a shirt with a jacket, then an armored vest. I have ran into a problem with the body parts of the player clipping through the clothes.

For more information on what I tried and what others have told me refer to:

https://blenderartists.org/t/trying-to-get-changeable-clothes-to-work/1171090

The best solution I like the most is:

"If you can get away with hiding parts of the skin (like the armpits), then do so.

You can also load mask textures onto your body to clip fragments/pixels in the shader, depending on the state of the clothing, so that your armpits are only invisible when wearing a hoodie, not when wearing a tank top.

Otherwise, the best technique I’ve found to eliminate body/clothing clipping, on a body with autoweights, is to use a vertex weight proximity to blend between data transfer weights (from body, for tight sections) and autoweights (for loose sections)."

The problem is I have no Idea how to implement this in blender and unity.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What specific step do you need help implementing? The instructions for setting up masks for clipping will not be the same as the instructions for adjusting the blend weights of your vertices. So ask about one step at a time (you can always post a second question later for the next step if you can't figure out where to go from there)

Comment: I'm just trying to get the body to stop clipping through the clothing. Also I am doing this for a game I am making on the unity engine so I can't use any special features that are unique to only blender. Any ideas?

Comment: The advice you received was good. Do that. If there's one specific part of the advice you don't know how to implement, then ask about that specific part.

Comment: how do I do humanartist's sugestion?